# how to see the images on user end from screenshot encoded into base64 from client side

Tags: javascript

This is the screen shot clicked and image is encoded to base64 string, as this is taken on client location now i want to access the same on my location so i am not able to see the images in it

The function i am using is generate() on click of a button
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/enLrdd5z/10/) this link contains base64 encoded string.

```
function screenshotPage() {
                urlsToAbsolute(document.images);
                urlsToAbsolute(document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']"));
                var screenshot = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
                var b = document.createElement('base');
                b.href = document.location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
                var head = screenshot.querySelector('head');
                head.insertBefore(b, head.firstChild);
                screenshot.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                screenshot.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                screenshot.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
                screenshot.style.mozUserSelect = 'none';
                screenshot.style.msUserSelect = 'none';
                screenshot.style.oUserSelect = 'none';
                screenshot.style.userSelect = 'none';
                screenshot.dataset.scrollX = window.scrollX;
                screenshot.dataset.scrollY = window.scrollY;
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.textContent = '(' + addOnPageLoad_.toString() + ')();';
                screenshot.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
                var blob = new Blob([screenshot.outerHTML], {
                    type: 'text/html'
                });
                var reader = new window.FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    base64data = reader.result;
                };
                if(base64data)
                {
                    data = base64data.substring(base64data.indexOf(",")+1, base64data.length);
                    text = data+space;
                    arr.push(text);
                }
                /*else{
                    alert("No image recieved /n Please press screenshot button");
                }*/
                return blob;
            }

        function addOnPageLoad_() {
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
                var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
                var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
                window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
            });
        }

        function generate() {
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(screenshotPage()));

        }
        exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
        exports.generate = generate;




    })(window);
```

Comment: You want to read image from base64 string?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is captured on client side and the blob object is taken and through that we are downloading that blob in text file. Then we are using the decoder to see that image but image is not loaded in that decoded html file.

Comment: How did you try to show that string?

Comment: By downloading that string into text file we are using that online decoder tool that is converting that text file into html file

Comment: but this is working on the client side system as if that text i copied in decoder then i am not able to look that image